# Double Linked List vs Array in Text Editors

Tags: c, text-processing

I started an experimental code editor, using ncurses. I'm using a double linked list for storing/parsing/printing the text. Even though I'm far into the implementation, I haven't quite decided if using a double linked list was the best idea or not (as opposed to using arrays).

Note that when I mean arrays, I mean an array of characters per line - not a single linear array.

Here's how I weighed the pros and cons:

Double Linked Lists:

- Faster character and line insertion
- Faster code folding

Arrays:

- Use less memory
- Much Faster parsing
- Faster printing
  Was I right to use linked lists? Or, is they a better way of doing this?

Note:

Arrays are printed faster because there only has to be one call to `printw` that prints an entire line. As opposed to calling `printw` per character.

Comment: This may be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Are you sure arrays are faster for printing? I would think they would be the same speed for that. Also if you use arrays every characters must have the same length, where as a linked list allows for mixed lengths (its weird when 'i' takes as much space as 'W')

Comment: @Dgrin91, yes. Arrays (strings) are faster for printing because you only have to call `printw` once per line - as opposed to calling it for every character (in a llist). Also, arrays can change size as well, and they don't have to have similar sizes either. I'm not quite sure what you meant by that.

Comment: Why not use a (doubly linked) list of strings, where each item in the list is a line, so you can call `printw()` once per line as with arrays.  You'd also dramatically reduce the storage requirement; on a 64-bit machine, a doubly linked list of single characters would likely use 24 bytes per character, which is quite a high overhead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I actually just started doing that. It does seem like a pretty decent compromise (I have a hunch that it's what `nano` uses). I'm probably going to delete this question, because I think that's my solution I'll be working with. Also, is it a bad idea to use `realloc` at every insertion/removal?

Comment: I'd probably design the list nodes along the lines of `struct Line { struct Line *next; struct Line *prev; char *line; size_t line_len; size_t line_max; };` with `line_len` recording the current line length, and the `line_max` recording the allocated space.  I'd not call `realloc()` when a character was deleted; I'd probably not do it unless there was some fairly large (256 byte?) discrepancy between the actual and the maximum size.  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ For insertions, I'd only reallocate when there was no longer space (when `line_len == line_max`, but beware off-by-one) and I'd allocate in increments of at least 16 characters (because that's likely the minimum amount that `malloc()` et al actually allocate anyway, plus when the user inserts one character, they often insert several).  So, you want to avoid per-character changes to the memory allocation (calls to `realloc()`), without being afraid to reallocate when necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, I'll start allocating `16` bytes at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Transferring comments into an answer since no-one else is chipping in.*

Why not use a (doubly linked) list of strings, where each item in the list is a line, so you can call `printw()` once per line as with arrays? You'd also dramatically reduce the storage requirement; on a 64-bit machine, a doubly linked list of single characters would likely use 24 bytes per character, which is quite a high overhead.

> I actually just started doing that. It does seem like a pretty decent compromise (I have a hunch that it's what nano uses). I'm probably going to delete this question, because I think that's my solution I'll be working with. Also, is it a bad idea to use `realloc()` at every insertion/removal?

I'd probably design the list nodes along the lines of:

```
struct Line
{
    struct Line *next;
    struct Line *prev;
    char        *line;
    size_t       line_len;
    size_t       line_max;
};
```

with `line_len` recording the current line length, and `line_max` recording the allocated space.

I'd not call `realloc()` when a character was deleted; I'd probably not do it unless there was some fairly large (256 byte?) discrepancy between the actual and the maximum size.

For insertions, I'd only reallocate when there was no longer space (when `line_len == line_max`, but beware off-by-one) and I'd allocate in increments of at least 16 characters (because that's likely the minimum amount that `malloc()` et al actually allocate anyway, plus when the user inserts one character, they often insert several). So, you want to avoid per-character changes to the memory allocation (calls to `realloc()`), without being afraid to reallocate when necessary.

Comment: thanks. What about if I ported to `cpp` and used `std::string`? Would that use a lot more memory? I'm considering it just because the string insertion and remove is already done with the `string` class. And, it can also resize the string in `n-byte` blocks easily.